# Plotting gBM issues

Tags: computational-finance

[Geometric Brownian motion (gBM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) is a stochastic process and can be thought of as an extension of standard Brownian motion.

I am trying to write a function that simulates different paths (`ntraj` paths) of gBM and then plots a histogram at certain points specified in a list `tcheck`. Once it has plotted these plots the function is meant to superimpose a lognormal distribution on the plot for each time.

The output is meant to look like this
[image]

except for gBM rather than a standard Brownian motion process. So far I have a function to generate multiple paths of gBM as,

```
def oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=100,n=100,T=1.0,sigma=1,mu=0):
    '''
    DOCSTRING:
    1D geomwtric brownian motion
    INPUTS:
    ntraj = "number of trajectories"
    n = "length of a trajectory"
    T = "last time point, i.e final tradjectory t = {0,1,...,T}"
    sigma= volatility
    mu= percentage drift

    '''
    np.random.seed(52323)
    S_0 = 0

    # Discretize, dt =  time step = $t_{j+1}- t_{j}$
    dt = T/(n)  
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

    # Container for different colors for each trajectory
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,nTraj))
    # Container for trajectories
    xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    ztraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    trange=np.linspace(start = 0,stop = T ,num = n+1)

    # Simulation
    # Random Variable $X_{n}$ is distributed np.sqrt(dt)* N(mu=0,sigma=1) 
    for j in range(nTraj):
        # Loop over time
        for i in range(n):
            xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+ sqrtdt * np.random.randn() + dt*mu
        # Loop again over time in order to make geometric drift
        ztraj = S_0 * np.exp(xtraj) # ztraj[z+1]=  ztraj[0]+ np.exp(xtraj[z])

        plt.plot(trange , xtraj,'b-',alpha=0.2, color=colors[j], lw=3.0,label="$\sigma$={}, $\mu$={:.5f}".format(sigma,mu))
    plt.title("1D Geometric Brownian Motion:\n nTraj={}, T={},\n $\Delta t$={:.3f}, $\sigma$={}, $\mu$={:.3f}".format(nTraj,T,dt,sigma,mu))    
    plt.xlabel(r'$t$')
    plt.ylabel(r'$Z_t$');

oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**3,T=10.0,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)
```

[image]

I have seen many answers to questions on how to plot multiple paths of gBM but I am interested in how to get look at the histograms at specific times and then look at the distribution. Below is my function so far. It is not working but I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I also added the output I got.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
ntraj = 10000
S_0 =0
sigma=1
mu=1
tfinal = 4.0
tcheck = [0.5, 1.0, 4.0]
dt = 0.01
xv = 1.0
'''
ntraj = 10**4
tfinal = 4.0
tcheck = [0.5, 1.0, 4.0]
dt = 0.01
xv = 5.0 # limits
'''
n=int(tfinal/dt)
sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

x=np.zeros(shape=[ntraj,n+1], dtype=float)
z=np.zeros(shape=[ntraj,n+1], dtype=float)
zrange=np.arange(start=-xv, stop=xv, step=dt)

# Calculate the number of the bins 
binval = math.ceil(np.sqrt(ntraj))
# Nested for loop to create Drifted BM
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(ntraj):
        x[j,i+1]=x[j,i]+ sqrtdt*np.random.randn()


 #Nested loop to create gBM
for j0 in range(ntraj):
    for i0 in range(n+1):
        z[j0,i0] = 0 + np.exp(x[j0,i0])

# Loop to plot the distribution of gBM tradjectories at different times       
for i1 in range(n):
    # Compute histogram at every tsample , sample at time t
    t=(i1+1)*dt
    if t in tcheck:
       # Plot histogram on sample
       plt.hist(z[:,i1],bins=30,density=False,alpha=0.6,label=['t ={}'.format(t)] )
       # Superimpose each samples mean
       xbar = np.average(z[:,i1])
       plt.axvline(xbar, color='RED', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) 
       # Plot theoretic distribution { N(0, sqrt[t] ) }
       #plt.plot(xrange,norm.pdf(xrange,0.0,np.sqrt(t)),'k--')
```

[image]

So to summarize my question. I am trying to simulate multiple trajectories of gBM, store my results in an array then loop over this array and plot a histogram over the specific points using matplotlib then lastly superimpose a lognormal distribution on my histograms.

Edit 1:

I need to superimpose the lognormal distribution on the GBM and the Cauchy if possible. My problem is that when I edited the correction by @Paul Harris I got,
[image]

```
def oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=100,n=100,T=1.0,sigma=1,mu=0):
    '''
    DOCSTRING:
    INPUTS:
    ntraj = "number of trajectories"
    n = "length of a trajectory"
    T = "last time point, i.e final tradjectory t = {0,1,...,T}"
    sigma= volatility
    mu= percentage drift

    '''
    np.random.seed(52323)
    S0 = 10

    # Discretize, dt =  time step = $t_{j+1}- t_{j}$
    dt = T/(n)  
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

    # Container for different colors for each trajectory
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,nTraj))
    # Container for trajectories
    xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    ztraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    trange=np.linspace(start = 0,stop = T ,num = n+1)

    out = []
    # Simulation
    # Random Variable $X_{n}$ is distributed np.sqrt(dt)* N(mu=0,sigma=1) 
    for j in range(nTraj):
        # Loop over time
        for i in range(n):
            xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+ sqrtdt * np.random.randn() + dt*mu

        # Loop again over time in order to make geometric drift
    ztraj = S0 * np.exp(xtraj)
    # Return gBM 
    return ztraj

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=plt.figaspect(1./2))

colors = ['k', 'r', 'b']
T =  [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]
sigma=0.8
mu=1.1 

for c, T in zip(colors, T):
    ztraj = oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**4,T=T,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)
    # Plot Emperical Values
    xrange = range(0,80,1)
    ax[0].hist(ztraj, bins=100, alpha=0.5, label=f'T={T}', density=True, color=c, range=(0, 95))

    # Plot the theoretical values
    theoretic_mean = math.exp(mu * T + 0.5 * sigma**2 * T)
    theoretic_var = math.exp(2* mu * T + sigma**2 * T)* (math.exp(sigma**2 * T) - 1)
    ax[0].plot(xrange,lognorm.pdf(xrange, theoretic_mean , theoretic_var ),'k--')

    # Plot the differences between consecutive elements of gBM (an array)
    diff = np.ediff1d(ztraj)
    ax[1].hist(diff, bins=100, alpha=0.5, label=f'T={T}', density=True, color=c, range=(-5, 5))


ax[0].set_xlabel('z')
ax[0].set_ylabel('$p(z,T)$')
ax[0].set_title('Histogram of ztraj positions')

ax[1].set_xlabel('dz')
ax[1].set_ylabel('$p(dz,T)$')
ax[1].set_title('Histogram of d(ztraj) positions\nbetween time steps')

ax[0].legend()
fig.tight_layout()
```

So to summarize I need to superimpose the distribution at each time point, the theoretical distribution for the gBM which is the lognormal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have had a look at your problem. I have edited your function to stop plotting and return `xtraj` which I assume is your Brownian motion:

```
def oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=100,n=100,T=1.0,sigma=1,mu=0):
    '''
    DOCSTRING:
    1D geomwtric brownian motion
    INPUTS:
    ntraj = "number of trajectories"
    n = "length of a trajectory"
    T = "last time point, i.e final tradjectory t = {0,1,...,T}"
    sigma= volatility
    mu= percentage drift

    '''
    np.random.seed(52323)
    S_0 = 10

    # Discretize, dt =  time step = $t_{j+1}- t_{j}$
    dt = T/(n)  
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

    # Container for different colors for each trajectory
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,nTraj))
    # Container for trajectories
    xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    ztraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)
    trange=np.linspace(start = 0,stop = T ,num = n+1)

    out = []
    # Simulation
    # Random Variable $X_{n}$ is distributed np.sqrt(dt)* N(mu=0,sigma=1) 
    for j in range(nTraj):
        # Loop over time
        for i in range(n):
            xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+ sqrtdt * np.random.randn() + dt*mu

        # Loop again over time in order to make geometric drift
    ztraj = S_0 * np.exp(xtraj) # ztraj[z+1]=  ztraj[0]+ np.exp(xtraj[z])

    return ztraj
```

The displacement per time step is then the differences within the array xtraj: `dx = np.ediff1d(oneDGeometricBM(...))`, so we compute a histogram of those values:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(np.ediff1d(oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**3,T=10.0,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)), bins=50, alpha=0.5, label='T=10', density=True)
ax.hist(np.ediff1d(oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**3,T=1.0,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)), bins=50, alpha=0.5, color='k', label='T=1', density=True)
ax.hist(np.ediff1d(oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**3,T=5.0,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)), bins=50, alpha=0.5, color='r', label='T=5', density=True)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('$p(x,T)$')

ax.legend()
```

[image: output]

I have used 3 different `T` values, as in the example. To normalise the histogram such that the y-axis now represents probability `p(x,T)`, ie. sum of all `p*x = 1`, we use the `density=True` argument.

EDIT

I have edited the `oneDGeometricBM` function to return `ztraj = S0*np.exp(xtraj)`. Your initial `S0` value was `0`, so I have made it non-zero.

You can plot `ztraj` differences as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colors = ['k', 'r', 'b']
T = [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]

for c, T in zip(colors, T):
    ztraj = oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**3,T=T,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)
    diff = np.ediff1d(ztraj)
    ax.hist(diff, bins=100, alpha=0.5, label=f'T={T}', density=True, color=c, range=(-10, 10))

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('$p(x,T)$')

ax.legend()
```

[image: ztraj]

EDIT2

From looking more closely at your produced histograms I think your modelling was correct, just the xrange of the plot should be adjusted as `ztraj` gets large for large `T`, you can limit the histogram using the `range` argument. So I have plotted `ztraj` and `d(ztraj)` for three separate `T`. `ztraj` does appear to approximately follow a log-normal distribution and the difference in `ztraj` appears to approximately follow a Lorentzian distribution (have to check theory on that one, maybe Gaussian). Code to reproduce:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=plt.figaspect(1./2))

colors = ['k', 'r', 'b']
T = [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]

for c, T in zip(colors, T):
    ztraj = oneDGeometricBM(nTraj=5,n=10**4,T=T,sigma=0.8,mu=1.1)

    ax[0].hist(ztraj, bins=100, alpha=0.5, label=f'T={T}', density=True, color=c, range=(0, 95))

    diff = np.ediff1d(ztraj)
    ax[1].hist(diff, bins=100, alpha=0.5, label=f'T={T}', density=True, color=c, range=(-5, 5))

ax[0].set_xlabel('z')
ax[0].set_ylabel('$p(z,T)$')
ax[0].set_title('Histogram of ztraj positions')

ax[1].set_xlabel('dz')
ax[1].set_ylabel('$p(dz,T)$')
ax[1].set_title('Histogram of d(ztraj) positions\nbetween time steps')

ax[0].legend()
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: ztraj and dz]

And here is your data and plot but limiting the histogram `range=(0, 10)`:

[image: og plot]

EDIT3

I have included code to fit the lognormal distributions and shown them on your original plot. We define the [lognormal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) as:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lognorm(x, x0, A, sigma):
    return A * np.exp(-(np.log(x)-x0)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
```

and then fit using the values and bins from the histogram in the final loop as:

```
# Loop to plot the distribution of gBM tradjectories at different times       
for i1 in range(n):
    # Compute histogram at every tsample , sample at time t
    t=(i1+1)*dt
    if t in tcheck:
        # Plot histogram on sample
        v, b, patches = plt.hist(z[:,i1],bins=200,density=False,alpha=0.6,label=['t ={}'.format(t)], range=(0, 10) )

        # second term is bin centre locations rather than bin edges
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(lognorm, b[:-1] + np.ediff1d(b), v, p0=(0.1, 300, 0.3))

        # make colors match their original data but no transparency
        plt.plot(b, lognorm(b, *popt), color=patches[0].get_facecolor()[:3])

        print(f'tcheck: {t} with parameters: {popt}')
```

Output:

```
tcheck: 0.5 with parameters: [ -0.42334757 358.38545736   0.6748076 ]
tcheck: 1.0 with parameters: [ -0.90719967 321.03944864   0.96137893]
tcheck: 4.0 with parameters: [ -3.66426932 721.41708932   1.86376987]
```

[image: lognormal fit]

EDIT4

The whole code to generate the above output would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lognorm(x, x0, A, sigma):
    return A * np.exp(-(np.log(x)-x0)**2 / (2*sigma**2))

ntraj = 10000
S_0 =0
sigma=1
mu=1
tfinal = 4.0
tcheck = [0.5, 1.0, 4.0]
dt = 0.01
xv = 1.0
'''
ntraj = 10**4
tfinal = 4.0
tcheck = [0.5, 1.0, 4.0]
dt = 0.01
xv = 5.0 # limits
'''
n=int(tfinal/dt)
sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)

x=np.zeros(shape=[ntraj,n+1], dtype=float)
z=np.zeros(shape=[ntraj,n+1], dtype=float)
zrange=np.arange(start=-xv, stop=xv, step=dt)

# Calculate the number of the bins 
binval = math.ceil(np.sqrt(ntraj))
# Nested for loop to create Drifted BM
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(ntraj):
        x[j,i+1]=x[j,i]+ sqrtdt*np.random.randn()


 #Nested loop to create gBM
for j0 in range(ntraj):
    for i0 in range(n+1):
        z[j0,i0] = 0 + np.exp(x[j0,i0])

# Loop to plot the distribution of gBM tradjectories at different times       
for i1 in range(n):
    # Compute histogram at every tsample , sample at time t
    t=(i1+1)*dt
    if t in tcheck:
        # Plot histogram on sample
        v, b, patches = plt.hist(z[:,i1],bins=200,density=True,alpha=0.6,label=['t ={}'.format(t)], range=(0, 10))

        popt, pcov = curve_fit(lognorm, b[:-1] + np.ediff1d(b), v, p0=(0.1, 300, 0.3))
        # make colors match their original data but no transparency
        plt.plot(b, lognorm(b, *popt), color=patches[0].get_facecolor()[:3])

        print(f'tcheck: {t} for parameters: {popt}')
```

Comment: Hi Paddy, this would be the drifted Brownian motion in the xtraj. The ztraj is what I am trying to use which is equal to the constant S_0 multiplpied with the exponential of the xtraj array.

Comment: something like this Z_{t} = Z_{0} exp( X_{t} )  where Z_{0} =  S_{0}

Comment: Okay, I have edit my answer to plot `d(ztraj)`. The function looks to to be quite sensitive to `S0` from my testing.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the lognormal fits- they fit quite well!

Comment: Hey @Paddy Harrison, sorru I am a bit lost in this solution, I am struggling to see where you put the loop, with all the editing. Could you share the complete solution with the loop that superimposes the lognormal? Sorry I am relatively new to python and often get stuck in the indentation.

Comment: @ThamuMnyulwa no problem, I've just edited my answer above to provide the whole running code. The gist of it is that the `lognormal` function must be defined before being called, so I've put it after the imports, and in the final loop we use the histogram bins and counts data to fit a lognormal function using `curve_fit` . The final plotting line in the loop shows the fit on the plot.